# Resize video frame using FFMPEG

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I need to resize the camera preview frame using ffmpeg. I have done writing the ffmpeg code and related java code what I'm doing is to send byte[] to native code and get the output in other byte[] but I'm always getting output buffer zero in my native code.

Here is my native code:

```
jint Java_com_sample_FfmpegNdk_resizeRawImage( JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jbyteArray input_array, jarray output_array, jint width, jint height) {
    jbyte *data;
    jsize array_size = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, input_array);

    data = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, input_array, NULL);

    LOGD_CUSTOM(env, "Data Length: (%d)", strlen(data));
    LOGD_CUSTOM(env, "Array Length: (%d)", array_size);

    AVFrame *frame1 = av_frame_alloc();
    avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)frame1, data, AV_PIX_FMT_NV12, 720, 480);

    struct SwsContext *resize;
    resize = sws_getContext(720, 480, AV_PIX_FMT_NV12, width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_NV12, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    AVFrame* frame2 = av_frame_alloc();

    int num_bytes = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_NV12, width, height);

    uint8_t* frame2_buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(num_bytes);

    avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)frame2, frame2_buffer, AV_PIX_FMT_NV12, width, height);

    LOGD_CUSTOM(env, "Frame1 Data: (%d)", strlen(frame1->data));

    sws_scale(resize, frame1->data, frame1->linesize, 0, height, frame2->data, frame2->linesize);

    LOGD_CUSTOM(env, "Frame2 Data: (%d)", strlen(frame2->data));

    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, output_array, (jbyte*)frame2->data, JNI_ABORT);

    jsize array_size_s = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, output_array);

    LOGD_CUSTOM(env, "Array Length After: (%d)", array_size_s);

    sws_freeContext(resize);

    free(data);

    return 0;
 }
```

And this is my code from where I'm getting camera preview

```
myCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        if (data != null) { 
            byte[] new_data = new byte[1024];
            Log.e("lenght", "IIp lenght : " + data.length);
            FfmpegNdk.resizeRawImage(data, new_data, 480, 270);
            Log.e("lenght", "oIp lenght : " + new_data.length);             
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `JNI_ABORT` is the reason for that, the flag prevents JVM from copying back the data to the client.

try changing this line

```
(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, output_array, (jbyte*)frame2->data, JNI_ABORT);
```

to

```
(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, output_array, (jbyte*)frame2->data, JNI_COMMIT);
```

`JNI_COMMIT` will copy back the data, and you will need to free the frame buffer with

```
av_frame_free(&frame2)
```

for more info please check 
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#arrays

Comment: I tried your solution but still its not working. I'm still getting Frame2 Data size 0. :(